# How do I thread these functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying to code an alarm in python that has 6 functions that need to multithread. 5 of these are alarms and one of them displays the time. The threads need to start and stop whenever the menu option is selected and when the alarm rings. The Display thread is the only thread that keeps going until the program stops. My current code for the alarm looks like this (I've removed a lot for the sake of clarity)

```
class TAlarm1 (threading.Thread):
    def Alarm1():
        while True:
            #code which keeps running until the time is equal to the input given (expected to thread)

                            
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=TAlarm1)
thread1.start()

            
def AlarmSelector():
    print("Select an Alarm") #5 alarms will be added however each one accomplishes the same task. all of them need to run simultaneously
    choice = int(input())
    if choice == 1:
        ala = TAlarm1()
        ala.Alarm1()
    if choice == 6:
        DisplayTime() #goes back to displaying time
```

Whenever I run this code, the program displays no errors however it does not run the code in TAlarm1().
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why did you create a `Thread` subclass without overriding the `run` method then use that class as the target argument to threading.Thread? Then you never use `thread1`. Your intent is a little hazy and it looks like you may have asked a number of questions in the form of `please fix everything that is wrong with this`.

Answer (score 0):

While your intent isn't clear to me. Here is how you can subclass Thread with its run method overridden and start it conditionally.

```
import threading
class TAlarm1 (threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        n =4
        while True:
            #code which keeps running until the time is equal to the input given (expected to thread)
            print(n,end=' | ')
            n -= 1
            if n < 0:
                break
        print()

t1 = TAlarm1()
if True:
    t1.start()
```

A thread can only be started once  so you have to make a new one every time you need it to run.

```
>>> t = TAlarm1() 
>>> t.start()
4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 
>>> t.start()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 848, in start
    raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once
>>> t = TAlarm1()
>>> t.start()
4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `target` parameter of `Thread` takes a *callable*.  A class is a callable, but calling it just creates an instance of the class.  Pass it a *function* instead:

```
import threading

def Alarm1():
    print('Alarm1 called')
                            
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=Alarm1)
thread1.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways of implementing threaded code in Python. You seem to have half of each.

The first implementation model is to put the logic to run in the thread into a function, then pass that function as the `target` argument when you create a `threading.Thread` instance:

```
import threading
import time

def worker(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.5)

my_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(10,))
my_thread.start()

# do other stuff in the main thread, if desired

my_thread.join()
```

The other implementation approach is to subclass `threading.Thread` and put the code to be run in the thread inside of the `run` method (or in other methods called from `run`). This is especially useful if your thread code has some complicated state and you want to be able to use additional methods to manipulate that state while the thread is running:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, n):
        super().__init__()
        self.n = n
        self.unpaused = threading.Event()
        self.unpaused.set() # we start unpaused

    def run(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            self.unpaused.wait() # block if we're paused
            print(i)
            time.sleep(0.5)

    def pause(self):
        self.unpaused.clear()

    def unpause(self):
        self.unpaused.set()

my_thread = MyThread(10)
my_thread.start()

# an example of inter-thread communication, we pause and unpause our thread using its methods
time.sleep(2)
my_thread.pause()
time.sleep(2)
my_thread.unpause()

my_thread.join()
```